# WinRar compressing with Batch

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I would like to use batch and winrar to compress certain files and save them as .scs.
The whole thing just doesn't want to work at the end.

Manually see it from the settings:
[image: Settings Image]

The batch code looks like this:

```
rar a -m0 -ep -u -x "finkenwerder.scs" def map material**.
```

It almost fits the file size, but when I let the file run in the game, it tells me it doesn't work.

If I complete it manually, the file will work.

Comment: what exactly are you compressing into the file? what are the exact directories/files?

Comment: [Folders](https://i.imgur.com/jrhlOD0.png)
i will these folder compression with my batch file. but it will not correctly working

Comment: I cannot see the image, just name me the exact folders and are they in the same directory?

Comment: thats the folder content [>Pastebin<](https://pastebin.com/dhVUpTMk)

Comment: Ok, thanks. When you manually compress it, do you include the folders Map, Def and Material, or just their content?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of whether you need to actually include the folders to the archive or not, so here are 2 solutions. Firstly `-x` switch is not needed as you are not excluding files.

If you need to include the folders, then use this  method. Also please include the full paths to your directories instead as it ensure you do not have issues with paths.

```
rar a -m0 -u "C:\path\to\file\finkenwerder.scs" "C:\game\def" "C:\game\map" "C:\game\material"
```

if you need only the files, and not the directories `map` `def` and `material` then do this

```
rar a -m0 -ep -u "C:\path\to\file\finkenwerder.scs" "C:\game\def" "C:\game\map" "C:\game\material"
```

lastly, you can also run the switches via batch, but using the GUI WinRAR using the same method as above.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar" a -m0 -u "C:\path\to\file\finkenwerder.scs" "C:\game\def" "C:\game\map" "C:\game\material"
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR" a -m0 -ep -u "C:\path\to\file\finkenwerder.scs" "C:\game\def" "C:\game\map" "C:\game\material"
```

Comment: I have testing your results one and two, but it will not working :/

The editor mean the map can not be loading.
And i need the folders for the scs file.

Comment: `rar a -m0 -u "finkenwerder.scs" def map material` should then work, I tested it now and it compresses the folders and content.

Comment: sure, he compressed it, but the game editor accept not the file.

when i compressed it manually (format = zip & compressmethod = save) with the name "finkenwerder.scs", then it works in the editor.

Comment: What happens if you use WinRAR's repair on the archive before using it, or  possibly Damaged Archives Repair Tool, [D.A.R.T](https://forum.scssoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=192120).

Comment: [Click here for the image](https://imgur.com/a/36A0j)

1. Format = ZIP, 2. Compressmethod = saving